# Replacing with context information

Tags: replace, forward-search

When writing latex sometimes I reuse old documents that use the `siunitx` package and use the `\SI` command. Then I often want to include the calculations via `pythontex` and replace (in a region) `\SI` with a modified command (see `pythontex` doc) called `\pySI[Session]` where in most cases `Session` is the last session in the document.

Consider this example:

```
\begin{pycode}[SessionA]
from numpy import 
a = 3
b = 4
c  = sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
\end{pycode}
```

In this text I previously had `\(a = \SI{3}{\m}\)` and `\(b = \SI{4}{\m}\)` and `\(c = \SI{5}{\m}\)`. But then I decided to add the pycode snipped above and want to replace it by `\(a = \pySI[SessionA]{a}{\m}\)` and `\(b = \pySI[SessionA]{b}{\m}\)` as well as `\(c = \pySI[SessionA]{c}{\m}\)`. This should even work, if I only marked this text and not the pycode environment above.

I tried the following code, but it seems to replace only `\SI` by `\pySI` but skips the session information:

```lisp
(defun my/latex-last-pycode-session ()
  (or (and (re-search-backward "^\\\\begin{pycode}\\[\\(.+\\)\\]\\s-*$" nil t)
           (format "[%s]" (match-string 1))
       )
      ""))

(defun try-replace-SI-to-PySI (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((session (my/latex-last-pycode-session)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char begin)
      (while 
      (re-search-forward
       "\\\\SI" end)
    (replace-match (format "\\\\pySI" session) 1)))))
```

What did I do wrong and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems:

- The `format` call is wrong: you need to say `(format "\\\\pySI%s" session)` to have the session info interpolated into the string.
- you need to tell `re-search-forward` to deal with errors more gracefully. You do that by adding a `t` as the last argument. Do `C-h f re-search-forward` and read the description of the `NOERROR` argument.
- your regexp is not capable of detecting the first argument of the `\SI` macro and changing it from the numeric value to the symbolic one (e.g. `3` to `a`). I'll leave that problem for you to worry about.

I should say: these are the problems that I can see - there may be more :-).

Comment: Thanks, too easy, I overlooked the `%s` :-). The third point has do be done manually, since the map from symbol to value doesn't need to be one to one (I didn't make that clear in my question, sorry).